# Create fancy box in node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, popup

I am new to node.js and i have got requirement of showing few screens as a `pop up/fancy box.` Is there any `module` to implement it OR any other suggestion to start with.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Usually popup works from client side, you should use any jquery library for creating popup. On node side you can manipulate the result or data that are sent to backend.

Answer (score 0):

When you mean you would like to have a gui, look into app.js, which allows you to spawn chrome windows and interact with them really cool.